# NHibernate map a column to a property and a bag

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm having some difficulties mapping the following sitation:

I have a person with a connection id, I use this to get map a bag and a property.
This works if the database already exists. But for our unit tests, we generate one from the schema, it gives an error : "duplicate column names".

Here is the mapping:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="DomainLayer.SearchDomain" assembly="Test">
  <class name="SearchPerson" table="person" lazy="false" mutable="false">
    <id name="Id" column="`id`" type="int">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="`NAAM`" type="string"  />
    <property name="FirstName" column="`VOORNAAM`" type="string"  />
    <property name="ConnectionId" column="`Koppelid`" type="int" />
    <bag name="Languages" lazy="false" mutable="false" access="field.camelcase-underscore">
      <key property-ref="ConnectionId" column="Koppelid" />
      <one-to-many class="DomainLayer.Person.LanguageSkill, Test" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Problem: "Koppelid" both in Key property from the bag as in the property.

**Edit:**

The LanguageSkill mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="DomainLayer.Person" assembly="Test">
  <class name="LanguageSkill" table="languageskill" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" type="Int32">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="ConnectionId" column="`KoppelId`" type="Int64"  />
    <property name="Remark" column="`Opmerking`" type="string"  />
    <property name="Source" column="`CdOorsprong`" type="string"  />
    <property name="MotherTongue" column="`moedertaal`" type="boolean"  />
    <property name="ModifiedDate" column="`wyzdat`" type="DateTime"  />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: the key column in the bag effects the other table not table WN so this can't be the problem. post the mapping of LanguageSkill as well because i suspect the error there

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The mapping of LanguageSkill contains a property ConnectionId (column name "koppelid"). I've added the language skill mapping in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should actually work. It may be because you have marked it with ` in one case, but not in the other.

Try this:

```
<bag ...>
    <key property-ref="ConnectionId" column="`Koppelid`" />
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot, didn't know it had this of an impact on the creation.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is actually that the column is defined twice in the LanguageSkillMapping. Since you mapped the column you could map it as reference and set the bag to inverse

```
<bag name="Languages" inverse="true" lazy="false" mutable="false" access="field.camelcase-underscore">
  <key property-ref="ConnectionId" column="Koppelid" />
  <one-to-many class="DomainLayer.Person.LanguageSkill, Test" />
</bag>


<many-to-one name="SearchPerson" column="`KoppelId`" />
```

Update: nevermind, Stefan got it

Comment: You're right about the inverse aswell, problem is this that I can't do this, as SearchPerson is strictly for a searchdomain and languageskill is in the normal domain.  But thanks anyway!